# Selecting fields from JSON, based on fields names and values

Tags: python, json, select

In python, I am getting a JSON from an API call.

```
resp = requests.get(url)
resp.json()
```

I am going to use my MySQL vocabulary.
This object I get is huge, with irregular structure (not all fields are available for each entry).

So I want to select in this JSON some fields and some entries based on values.
Let's say that the JSON returns profiles of users, with the fields `"name"`, `"email"`, and `"age"`.

I want to create a new small JSON having:

- Only one field "email" - we remove the entries not having an email field.
- Only when `"age"` = `15`

While in SQL I would do it in 30 seconds, I haven't found how to do it in Python...

Comment: Use a `for` loop, test whether the entry in the list matches your criteria, and add it to the result list.

Comment: `if "email" in entry and entry["age"] == 15: ...`

Comment: You might want a [jmespath filter](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections)

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit on the code to use?
It is super obvious I need a loop to review the entries, and an if.
But it does not tell me what's the syntax.
Thanks

Comment: @Barmar 
I don't see the connection with the duplicated topic you mentioned.
Different case.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. It seems like you just need to know how to access these fields. What you do with the data should be obvious once you get them.

Comment: The most Pythonic way to filter your response is a list comprehension (over your response) that applies your filter conditions in its `if` part, and you formulate these conditions in a way that is tolerant (but rejecting) towards missing fields:
`data = [ row for row in resp.json() if row.get("age", 0) == 15 and row.get("email") ]`

Answer (score 0):

You could you list comprehension for that - I think syntax would be the most similar to SQL

```
[obj for obj in res.json() if obj.email is not None and obj.age=="15"]
```

or use more functional approach

```
def yourCustomFilter(obj):
    return obj.email is not None and obj.age=="15"

filter(resp.json(), yourCustomFilter)
```

or simple for each loop

```
filteredObjects = []
for obj in resp.json():
    if obj.email is not None and obj.age=="15":
        filteredObjects.append(obj)
```